# Robotium : How can i test/check the values which i got on update screen are same as, the values which we have on one of the list view items

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I am learning "Robotium". I have one android application for testing.
In this application i want to test an "Update" record functionality using "Robotium + jUnit". I am having perfectly working environment.

**Working**:

On List view screen, some database records are shown(id, name, contact no) in list view (screen shot 1).

When user clicks on one of the list view items, pop-up appears on screen asking for "Update or Delete".

After clicking on "Update", another screen(Activity) opens and the values for id, name and contact number are shown in the respective edit texts which have been sent on this activity through intent by list view activity.(As shown in the screenshots).

1)List View Screen:

[image]

2) Pop-up

[image]

3)Update Screen

[image]

**Ok! Now my question is :**

How Can i test/check the values which i got on update screen are same as the values which we have on one of the list view items.

The code which i have written is as follows:

```
public void testUpdate()
{

    solo.clickOnButton("Show Db");
    solo.clickInList(3);            //list view screen
    solo.clickOnMenuItem("Update"); //Pop-up screen
    solo.clickOnButton("Update");   //Update screen

}
```

"solo.clickInList(3);" using this line of code i am able to click on the third item in the list view. But i need the whole text of this item for comparison.

So, Can anybody provide the code through which i can perform the intended testing things ? please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickInList will return an ArrayList with the text views located on the list line. So something like this should work String text = solo.clickInList(3).get(0).getText().toString();